# ng-file-upload accessing data sent in upload

Tags: ng-file-upload

I am sending my data like. I am new to angular. I am not able to access the userDetails in my post request.

Upload.upload({
      url: '/api/upload/',
      data: {'File': File, 'userDetails': userDetails}
    });

Server Code:

```
userRouter.route('/upload')
  .post(function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.data);
    upload(req, res, function(err) {
      if(err) {
        res.json({ error_code:1, err_desc:err });
        return;
      }
      res.json({ error_code:0, err_desc:null });
    })
  });
```

the field req.data is undefined

Comment: post your server code here since you cannot get it on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new on angularjs too and I had the same problem. I made use of https://github.com/expressjs/node-multiparty to get the data sent from ng-file-upload.
I hope it helps you too.